# What is the meaning of "<<<", ">>>", and "---" in maven output?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-javadoc-plugin

Here's a representative sample from my project's `mvn install`:

```
[INFO]                                                                       
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject REST 1.8.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-project-rules) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:unpack-dependencies (unpack-shared-resources) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] swagger-ui-1.4.1.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:javadoc (generate-service-docs) @ myproject-rest >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-project-rules) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:unpack-dependencies (unpack-shared-resources) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] swagger-ui-1.4.1.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:javadoc (generate-service-docs) @ myproject-rest <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:javadoc (generate-service-docs) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] Skipping javadoc generation
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ myproject-rest ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

Some lines are prefixed and suffixed with "<<<", some with ">>>", and some with "---".    What do they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`---` introduces the execution of a Maven plugin goal, with the exception of the following.

`>>>` introduces the execution of a Maven plugin goal that forks its own lifecycle.

`<<<` marks the end of a forked lifecycle.